# Is there a way to write this HAVING query with SUM in Eloquent without raw?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, having

```
select
    *
from
    `foundations`
inner join `foundation_sector` on
    `foundation_sector`.`foundation_id` = `foundations`.`id`
inner join `sectors` on
    `sectors`.`id` = `foundation_sector`.`sector_id`
GROUP BY
    foundations.id
HAVING
    SUM(sectors.title = 'x')
    AND SUM(sectors.title = 'y')
```

What I tried was

```
   $postQuery = Foundation::query()
            ->join('foundation_sector', 'foundation_sector.foundation_id', '=', 'foundations.id')
            ->join('sectors', 'sectors.id', '=', 'foundation_sector.sector_id')
            ->groupBy('foundations.id')
            ->having('sectors.title', 'sum', $sectors, 'and');
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: did you try `having(DB::raw(...))`? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: @RomanBobrik thanks for thinking along but I was especially curious about preventing raw as per title of the question

Comment: Keep in mind that `select
    * .. GROUP BY
    foundations.id`  can be invalid SQL which could result into invalid results -> consider the MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) regrading [Detection of Functional Dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: *"Is there a way to write this HAVING query with SUM in Eloquent without raw?"* ... You could "cheat" by making a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) and query that instead from laravel..

Comment: i understood, but as far i know there is no way to get `where` or `having` with aggregation without raw queries. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods.

Comment: by the way, i prefer to avoid `join` method in laravel. i'm using relations instead of it. i think it is more "laravel-way" and quite better to read code

Comment: @RomanBobrik How would you get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have still used raw, but prepared the statement also:

```
  $postQuery = Foundation::query()
            ->join('foundation_sector', 'foundation_sector.foundation_id', '=', 'foundations.id')
            ->join('sectors', 'sectors.id', '=', 'foundation_sector.sector_id')
            ->groupBy('foundations.id');

        foreach ($sectors as $sector) {
            $postQuery = $postQuery->havingRaw('SUM(sectors.title = ?)', [$sector]);
        }
```